# Most basic distributed Java - what method of communication should I use?

Tags: java, jaxb, rmi, xml-rpc, rpc

I'm developing a library which you can use in client or server code. More specifically, you create an instance of some class for the library and tell it to be a server or a client.

The client must send about 5 attributes to the server without any hierarchical structure, the server must answer with one attribute or some error description.

Client and server don't have to share any state, so if the server changes the information given by the client, the client doesn't have to know about these changes.

At the moment I decode everything into a string with a special separating charater and send it  over a TCP-Socket. I would like to have a bit more type-safety here and was thinking about using RMI, but as far as my short research went, RMI enforced a shared state on the object, which is not my goal. Therefore I might need some kind of web-service solution? Should I use JAXB to describe the messages and send xml messages over the socket? Is there some good library to send JAXB annotated object over the web and still have some control over communication, network, server failures?

The software should always be able to run on a basic JRE installation.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: JSON? Simple and easy to use.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "RMI enforced a shared state on the object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the technologies enumerated in the tags are good. You can also take a look at [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) and [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) for the communication. But I would not call them basic. Also JSON is a good way to go. JAXB is included in the JVM so it will work without any extra library.

Answer (score 0):

Another technology you might consider is [Versile Java](https://versile.com/products/vjava/) (full disclosure: I am a Versile developer); it is in development but already quite stable. See the link for a simple example. Versile Java performs object-level RMI and relies only on the standard Java library.

Versile Java is "basic" in the sense that the type of scenario you are describing is very easy to implement, without having to do any network-level programming (which is all handled internally by the platform). It is "not basic" in the sense it offers a lot more functionality than just passing immutable data structures.